# openGL rotation with respect to x axis in view coordinator

Tags: opengl

Suppose I have a starting view like this

[image]
With code

> gluLookAt(eye.x, eye.y, eye.z, ref.x, ref.y, ref.z,
>   viewup.x,viewup.y,viewup.z);

here

> (eye.x, eye.y, eye.z) = (5.0, 5.0, 10.0);
>   (ref.x, ref.y, ref.z) = (0,0, 0) ;
>   (viewup.x, viewup.y, viewup.z) = (0, 1, 0);

May I know how do I change eye.x, eye.y and eye.z's value so the view coordinate will have a rotation respect to x axis like the following two screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Is there a rotation matrix operation in view coordinate just like model coordinate's rotation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change eye.x and eye.y position, i mean you should change your camera position in gluLookAt function and mantain your lookAt reference in (0,0,0) or in the center of the cube. For the first screenshot you could try:

```
eye.x=0.0; 
eye.y=5.0;
eye.z=10.0;
```